# Unable to load a null value into SQL Server using a TableAdapter

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, parameters, null

I have read all the related entries (here and at other sites) and have not found my situation.

I have a table (MyTable) with several date fields (MyDateField1, MyDateField2, etc) plus other fields not pertinent to this matter.  All the date fields allow null values.

My application's tableadapter's insert method invokes the following stored procedure:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (@MyDateField1Value, @MyDateField2Value,..., <other fields>);
```

using this VB code (dv is a dataview):

```
NewRow = dv.AddNew
NewRow(MyDate1Field) = DateValue1  <some date value taken off a window>
NewRow(MyDate2Field) = DateValue2  <some date value taken off a window>
....
NewRow.EndEdit()

MyTableTableAdapter.Insert(DateValue1, DateValue2, <etc>)
```

This works fine when none of the date fields is null.  However, if I set:

```
NewRow(MyDate1Field) = DBNull.Value
```

I get the error message that DBNull.Value cannot be converted to a date value.  How can I get a null value into MyDateField1, MyDateField2, etc.

Comment: did you try a normal null?

Comment: That is all pretty horrible.  What is the point of that `DataView` at all?  You don't use when inserting so what's it for?  Are the parameters of that `Insert` method type `DateTime` or type `DateTime?`, which is the same as `Nullable(Of DateTime)`?  If it's the former then you need to change them to make them nullable and if it's the latter then you simply pass `Nothing`.

Comment: What's horrible about leaving out information that is totally irrelevant to my question? The data view serves as the binding source for all the user input controls on the window that this is code-behind.  When the user clicks on the "Save" button, the pseu-code I included is executed.  OK?  Now, I'd like to ask for your continued contribution to my education.  See next comment.

Comment: The parameters are all Date types.  The type DateTime? that you cited seems like it is what I am looking for but when I search for it, all I get are cites for datetime itself.  Can you provide links?  Also, neither SQL Server nor VB.net allow for the datetime? datatype so how  I would I use it?

Thanks ahead of time for your positive contribution.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to pass Nothing.  Very simple - too bad it was so hard to find.